# How to stop fingerprint scanner event

Tags: codenameone

I have implemented fingerprint scanner functionality using codename one.
On post form event I have written below code.

```
Fingerprint.scanFingerprint(value -> {
    Log.p("Scan successfull!");
   showForm("Home",null);
}, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
    Log.p("Scan Failed!");
    showForm("Login",null);
});
```

After succesful finger print scan "Home" form will open.But after displayed home form scanner event still active in background when I put my finger on scanner it scans fingerprint and again does the same thing.
I have to stop fingerprint scanner event after succesful or fail scan.
What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the Fingerprint Scanner but the post show event of your form.

You need to remove the show listener you are calling the Fingerprint scanner from or all show listeners if other features don't rely on this listener.

```
myForm.addShowListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        myForm.removeShowListener(this);//or myForm.removeAllShowListeners()
        Fingerprint.scanFingerprint(value -> {
            Log.p("Scan successfull!");
            showForm("Home",null);
        }, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
            Log.p("Scan Failed!");
            showForm("Login",null);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of how you are currently utilizing Fingerprint?

Comment: You can always just flip an "ignore" flag after the scan. On which OS is this happening?

Comment: Debug the app using DDMS to check for any errors. It may be due to permission not granted.